# A simple closed curve is longer than the largest inscribed circle

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

This may seem like a simple question but upon further thought it seems quite difficult (similar to the Jordan Curve Theorem). Stated thusly, my question is: Let $C$ be any simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $r$ be the radius of the largest circle that can be inscribed in $C$. Does this imply that the length of $C$ is greater than or equal to equal to $2\pi r$? This seems like a very obvious statement, but it goes beyond my limited knowledge to even begin to tackle this problem. Any terms I could research would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's true and not as difficult as the Jordan Curve Theorem. My line of proof would be to show the shortest (rectifiable) essential curve in the plane with open disk of radius $r$ removed is $2\pi r$. If nobody else answers, I'll try to supply details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an immediate corollary of the isoperimetric inequality: given a rectifiable closed curve $\gamma$ bounding a compact region $\Omega$, then:
$$\frac{Area(\Omega)}{lenght(\gamma)^2}\le \frac{1}{4\pi}$$

Indeed for your curve $\Omega\supset S$, $S$ being the inscribed circle. Hence
$$lenght(C)\ge\sqrt{4\pi Area(\Omega)}\ge\sqrt{4\pi Area(S)}=2\pi r$$

Of course, the isoperimetric inequality is quite a strong tool...

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for